# Single line text element vs Multi Line to list selected file names. I just cant make Multi Line work at all, please advise

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

> I made a GUI that displays the names of files the user selects in a
> file browser. It will display the file names in the single line
> element, no hassle, no worries. Now im trying to spice things up a
> little and have the file names listed in a multiline element.
> I just cant seem to get it to display anything, even when i comment out the line where the data gets displayed in the single line
> element, it still shows the data in the single line element, while the
> multi remains blank. Ive tried with and without keys, using the same
> FilesBrowse as the input. Nothing seems to work. Nothing seems to be
> showing in the multiline no matter what I do...
> Least importantly, the reset button doesnt really do what i want, if there is an easy way to have the window reset back to its blank,
> orgiginal state, ready for user imput, I would like to hear about it.

```
**# Define the function that will be run in a separate thread when the user clicks "Submit"**
def process_files(input_files):
    for i, input_file in enumerate(input_files):
        # Check if the file exists
        output_file = input_file.replace(".pdf", ".xlsx")
        if os.path.isfile(input_file):
            output_file = input_file.replace(".pdf", ".xlsx")
            try:
            # Run the PDF_Fix function from main2 module
                main2.PDF_Fix(input_file, output_file)
            except Exception as e:
                # Show an error message if something goes wrong
                sg.popup("An error occurred while processing the file: ", input_file, "Error message: ", e)
        else:
            # Show an error message if the file doesn't exist
            sg.popup("The file: ", input_file, " does not exist")
            # Update the progress bar
        window['progressbar'].update_bar(int((i + 1) / len(input_files) * 1000))
    window["Submit"].update(button_color=("white", "green"))
    window["Submit"].update(disabled=False)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Select your PDFs here:")],
    [sg.Input(disabled=True), sg.FilesBrowse(key="FilesBrowse")], # Input field and "Browse" button to select files
    [sg.Multiline(size=(45, 10), key="Output")],  # Output field to display selected file names
    [sg.ProgressBar(1000, orientation='h', size=(35, 20), key='progressbar')],  # Progress bar to show the progress of the process_files function
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Exit(), sg.Button("Reset")]
]

sg.theme('DarkTeal1')
window = sg.Window(title="B.M.U.B", layout=layout, margins=(100, 50))


def reset_form():
    window["FilesBrowse"].update("")
    window["Input"].update("")
    window["progressbar"].update_bar(0)
    window["Submit"].update(button_color=("white", "green"))
    window["Submit"].update(disabled=False)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == 'FilesBrowse':
        file_names = [os.path.basename(file) for file in values['FilesBrowse'].split(";")]
        print(file_names)
        window['Input'].update('\n'.join(values['FilesBrowse']))
        window['Output'].update('\n'.join(file_names))

    if event == 'Reset':
        reset_form()
    if event == 'Submit':
        input_files = values["FilesBrowse"].split(';')
        window["Submit"].update(button_color=("grey", "black"))
        window["Submit"].update(disabled=True)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=process_files, args=(input_files,), daemon=True)
        # start the thread that will run the process_files function in the background
        thread.start()

    elif event == 'Exit' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

I have even tried using print statements to put anything into the multiline box and i still get nothing, so i assume its some quirk im not aware of because i am very new at this.
The program itself is just taking PDFs and converting them into excel sheets and applying formatting to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to check if event generated by using print statement. There's no event 'FilesBrowse' generated in your code, so nothing happened.

Add `target='FileBrowse'` to `sg.FileBrowse`, also `enable_events=True`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(size=10, expand_x=True, key='-IN-')],
    [sg.Multiline('', size=(40, 10), key="-ML-")],
    [sg.Push(), sg.FilesBrowse(target='FileBrowse', enable_events=True, key='FileBrowse')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event)
    if event == 'FileBrowse':
        files = values[event]
        window['-IN-'].update(files)
        window['-ML-'].update('\n'.join(files.split(";")))

window.close()
```

or set target to another Input element, also with `enable_events=True`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(size=10, expand_x=True, disabled=True, enable_events=True, key='-IN-')],
    [sg.Multiline('', disabled=True, size=(40, 10), key="-ML-")],
    [sg.Push(), sg.FilesBrowse(target='-IN-', key='FileBrowse')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event)
    if event == '-IN-':
        files = values[event]
        window['-ML-'].update('\n'.join(files.split(";")))

window.close()
```